# Store and compare UNIX time or expiration days

Tags: sql, sqlite

I’m thinking of a project where I’ll use a SQL database to store rows with an expiration date measured in days. Every day I’ll clean the database of expired rows. I’m considering two solutions:

#### 1

Store `expiration` as an integer of days in the future. Then, every day:

1. Go through the database and subtract `1` to the `expiration` of each row.
2. Remove rows with an `expiration` of less than or equal to `0`.

#### 2

Store `expiration` as a UNIX time in the future. Then every day:

1. Search through the database for rows with an `expiration` of less than or equal to the current UNIX time.

It seems to me option **2** is superior because:

1. It’ll require less writing to the database. There may be days where nothing is written with option **2**, but option **1** will always modify every row.
2. If the maintenance script doesn’t run one day, **1** will be behind, while **2** can catch up.

So my questions:

1. Am I right? Is **2** the better option, or am I missing something?
2. Is there a third option that is overall superior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Relative** expiration times are inferior to **absolute** ones in the overwhelming majority of cases - just think what a missed (or worse: half-run) cron job could mean with relative times.

The only case I know of, where relative times are superior, is when they are needed in their relative form so often, that the necessary calculations start to make a difference. This is not realistic outside of a small number of very specialized applications.

So: Yes, using the UNIX timestamp of the expiry point in time makes more sense.